# Constructing a Markov transition rate matrix of a graph with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, transition

I have a question about constructing a [transition rate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) in Python, I have a transition graph which is described in dictionary:

```
    graph={((), ('a',)): [ 0.0],
           (('a',), ('b',)): [78.71428571428571],
           (('a',), ('c',)): [18.142857142857142],
           (('a',), ('d',)): [132.66666666666666],
           (('a',), ('e',)): [64.0],
           (('b',), ('a',)): [215.1139240506329],
           (('b',), ('c',)): [13.26923076923077],
           (('b',), ('d',)): [10.333333333333334],
           (('c',), ('a',)): [60.333333333333336],
           (('c',), ('b',)): [181.31034482758622],
           (('c',), ('d',)): [507.0],
           (('d',), ('a',)): [56.0],
           (('d',), ('b',)): [968.0],
           (('e',), ('a',)): [860.0]}
```

[image: graph of the transition rate matrix]

As you can see in the dictionary graph, the key illustrates the transitions and the value is the rate a continuous-time Markov chain moves between states. For example, from 'a' moves to 'b', the rate is 78.71428571428571, and so on. 
A simple example for the transition rate matrix for understanding:

```
    graph = {(('a',), ('b',)): 78.71428571428571, 
             (('a'), ('c',)): 18.142857142857142,
             (('c',), ('b',)): 181.31034482758622}
    #the corresponding matrix for this sample graph:
    q_matrix = np.asmatrix([[-96.85714285714285, 78.71428571428571,   18.142857142857142], 
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 181.31034482758622, -181.31034482758622]])
```

I tried to build an matrix for this question:

```
    M = [[0]*5 for _ in range(5)]
```

but the index in M doesn't match the transitions in the graph, any help?
Thanks